# pandas: pivoting on rank

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, dataframe

Given this data:

```
pd.DataFrame({'id':['aaa','aaa','abb','abb','abb','acd','acd','acd'],
              'loc':['US','UK','FR','US','IN','US','CN','CN']})

    id loc
0  aaa  US
1  aaa  UK
2  abb  FR
3  abb  US
4  abb  IN
5  acd  US
6  acd  CN
7  acd  CN
```

How do I pivot it to this:

```
 id   loc1   loc2   loc3
aaa    US     UK     None
abb    FR     US      IN
acd    US     CN      CN
```

I am looking for the most idiomatic method.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create new column `cols` with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and convert to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), last use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['cols'] = 'loc' + (df.groupby('id')['id'].cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
print df
    id loc  cols
0  aaa  US  loc1
1  aaa  UK  loc2
2  abb  FR  loc1
3  abb  US  loc2
4  abb  IN  loc3
5  acd  US  loc1
6  acd  CN  loc2
7  acd  CN  loc3

print df.pivot(index='id', columns='cols', values='loc')
cols loc1 loc2  loc3
id                  
aaa    US   UK  None
abb    FR   US    IN
acd    US   CN    CN
```

If you want remove index and columns names use [rename_axis](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename):

```
print df.pivot(index='id', columns='cols', values='loc').rename_axis(None)
                                                        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
    loc1 loc2  loc3
aaa   US   UK  None
abb   FR   US    IN
acd   US   CN    CN
```

All together, thank you [Colin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439311/pandas-pivoting-on-rank/36440202#comment60494960_36440202):

```
print pd.pivot(df['id'], 'loc' + (df.groupby('id').cumcount() + 1).astype(str), df['loc'])
        .rename_axis(None)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

    loc1 loc2  loc3
aaa   US   UK  None
abb   FR   US    IN
acd   US   CN    CN
```

I try [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html), but I get error in version `0.18.0`:

```
print df.groupby('id')['loc'].transform(lambda x: x.rank(method='first'))
#ValueError: first not supported for non-numeric data
```

Comment: This is a good answer.   Simplifying it slightly: `pd.pivot(df['id'], 'loc' + (df.groupby('id').cumcount() + 1).astype(str), df['loc'])`

Comment: great solution, but I'm running into [an issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456857/pandas-index-join-level-on-non-unique-index-is-not-implemented) applying it to real data.

Comment: If instead `pivot` use `pivot_table,` error is same?

Comment: no, then it's "index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0"