# pandas: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to adapt the answer to [pandas: pivoting on rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439311/pandas-pivoting-on-rank) to real data.  Running the offered solution:

```
pd.pivot(df['id'], df.groupby('id'), df['loc'])
        .rename_axis(None)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

on my data results in the error

> Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented

Looking at the stack trace, I see that the problem stems from

```
 /data/qps/dm-conda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape.py
 in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
     325             index = self.index
     326         else:
 --> 327             index = self[index]
     328         indexed = Series(self[values].values,
     329                          index=MultiIndex.from_arrays([index, self[columns]]))
```

which I was able to reproduce directly with simply:

```
df[df['serial']]
```

(where `df['serial']` is equivalent to `df['id']` in the example)

What do I need to look at in order to understand/troubleshoot the error?

Here's what `df`'s index looks like:

```
In [36]:df.index
Out[36]:
Int64Index([209442, 279040, 203222,  27126, 250496, 458622,   9012, 595219,
            289539,  82650,
            ...
            864328, 719640, 416547, 410042, 862238, 723387, 410729, 117068,
            413247, 412747],
           dtype='int64', length=9366)
 In [37]: df.index.is_unique
 Out[37]: True
```

and `df['serial']` is the unique index:

```
In [39]: df['serial'].index
Out[39]:
Int64Index([209442, 279040, 203222,  27126, 250496, 458622,   9012, 595219,
            289539,  82650,
            ...
            864328, 719640, 416547, 410042, 862238, 723387, 410729, 117068,
            413247, 412747],
           dtype='int64', length=9366)

In [40]: df['serial'].index.is_unique
Out[40]: True
```

The index appears to be unique, so what's causing the error?

Comment: What version of pandas use? If remove `rename_axis` is it working?

Comment: using 0.18.0.  Removing rename_axis doesn't help.  As I mentioned, the problem is reproducible with simply `df[df['serial']].  Sample data from the initial question works just fine, btw.

Comment: Maybe help [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

Comment: that didn't help...  I'm going to try reproducing this in a Python IDE and step through with a debugger.

Comment: Is possible share data?

Comment: Actually, it looks like if I export data as csv and then read it back in, everything starts working.  The df I'm applying the solution to is a result of several prior transformations, so there must be something weird about the state of the index.  I did try `reset_index` before applying the solution, but that didn't help.